# How to transform a JSON array of objects to an object containing arrays

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have json serialized written with JSON.NET that looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "A": "1",
            "B": "4"
        },
        {
            "A": "2",
            "B": "5"
        },
        {
            "A": "3",
            "B": "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea how can I change from multiple keys to one key with multiple values like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "A": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
        ],
        "B": [
            "4",
            "5",
            "6"
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Welcome to stackoverflow*! This site helps solving issues with **your code**. You post your code here when you have results which are different from expected, or when you get an error. You also should describe what results you have and what is expected and/or provide error details. After that community will help you to solve issues and (sometimes) it'll give you some guidance. That is how *stackoverflow* works. As you can see, your question doesn't have all appropriate information. Please **edit** your question and add code with other required information if you want to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) API:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

obj["data"] = new JObject(obj["data"]
    .Children<JObject>()
    .SelectMany(jo => jo.Properties())
    .GroupBy(jp => jp.Name)
    .Select(g => new JProperty(g.Key, new JArray(g.Values()))));

Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dXCdlO